# Sending AT commands to a modem

Tags: android, at-command

I am trying to implement an application that makes short calls with some time interval. I need the program to make a call within the given time, then the call stops, then pause and then all over again.
Here is some code sample, which runs when button clicked:

```
private String commCall = "echo -e \"ATD1234567890;\\r\" > /dev/smd0\n";
private String commStop = "echo -e \"AT+CHUP\\r\" > /dev/smd0\n";
private Runnable testRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(commCall);
            outputStream.flush();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            outputStream.writeBytes(commStop);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            su.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

So the code is right. Calls are starting and stopping. The problem is when I terminate programme (swiping in task menu) and then executing runnable again, modem starting call for some milliseconds and then freezes, and then android crash and reboot. The most strange thing that I can use in my program, they can make calls with dialer, then use the program again - all good. But if I(or android) kill app process, next time sending a command to modem causing the android reboot. What is wrong with my code, or maybe there is some other way to make calls with specified time and delays?

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the `DataOutputStream` within the scope of method `onDestroy`... also `Process.destroy()` might be required there - else it will not be properly clean up after itself, and might crash, when trying to open it again.

Comment: I added outputStream.close() and su.destroy() to the finally block. No changes... Android still crashes when restarting app and send new command (even if command is simple "AT")